# Calendar days in CalendarList component of react-native-calendars npm module seems disabled/grayed out in normal mode but works fine in debug mode

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, react-native, calendar

Calendar marked dates are working fine with debug mode but not in normal mode.(I am fetching marked dates from the backend)

But if i am running in normal or release mode, marking dates are disabling all the dates in calendar and gives the saved date as invalid date.

Reference for this issue on github : https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/438

Let me know if anyone would have faced the same issue.

I have gone through the react-native-calendars github repo , but then also  am not able to find the exact cause for the issue.

Even i am getting the selected dates as invalid date.You can see it at top of header in that dialog

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was regarding with the date format which i was passing.

Initially i was using normal Date() method and parsing the date to required format and sending it.But while receving it was converted to other format.

So, finally i found that date should be formatted to ISO standard.

Then i used moment() method to convert it to required format on which the issue got resolved.